# How to send data from eBPF code to Kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ebpf, bpf

I know we can send data from eBPF code to userspace through BPF Maps, but is there a way to send any kind of data from eBPF code to a kernel module?

This [link](https://lore.kernel.org/bpf/3490d887-ae2d-df07-fcdb-67b05b87f611@cambridgegreys.com/T/) showed a patch that adds functions in kernel to read data from BPF_MAP_TYPE_RINGBUF map. But it seems they have no plan to merge it into main kernel. And since compiling the kernel is not an option, I'm right back where I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet to make this work would be to implement [kfuncs](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/kfuncs.html) in your kernel module which you could call from your eBPF program. If you need to store any kind of data, implement it in the module instead of using maps.